# Autofac - Injecting Keyed service with NamedParameter into constructor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I have a Keyed service registered in Autofac that I would like to be injected via the constructor. 
The service is registered

```
builder.Register((ctx, par) =>
{
    var namedParameter = par.Named<string>("myNamedParameter");
    ... configuration and instantiation ...
}).Keyed<IMyService>(myKey);
```

and is currently being resolved explicitly

```
public class MyConsumer {
    private readonly IMyService _myService;

    //current
    public MyConsumer(ILifetimeScope scope) {
        _myService = _scope.ResolveKeyed<IMyService>(myKey, new NamedParameter("myNamedParameter", "parameterValue"));
    }

    //preferred
    public MyConsumer(IMyService myService) {
        _myService = myService;
    }
}
```

However, I haven't been able to find a way to have said service injected during construction. Autofac's `KeyFilterAttribute` only accepts a key; it doesn't appear to allow for `NamedParameters`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NamedService` is a specialized version of `KeyedService` where the key is of type `String`.

both

```
c.RegisterType<T>().Named<IT>("x"); 
c.RegisterType<T>().Keyed<IT>("x");
```

are equivalent.

You can use

```
public MyConsumer([KeyFilter("x")]IMyService myService) {
    _myService = myService;
}
```

and it will resolve the service named `"x"` of type `IMyService`